# Is there a way to find the default application for opening a particular file in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know that I can use  PackageManager.queryIntentActivities() to get a list of ResolveInfo objects. But what if the user has a default apllication set for the particular action( or file type). Is there a way to find which app is set as default for the action among the ResolveInfo objects retrieved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `resolveActivity()` on `PackageManager` to find out what would be started if you called `startActivity()` on the `Intent`. If that returns the activity chooser, then you know that there are multiple choices and none is set as the preferred app, so a chooser would appear. Also note that on some HTC devices in the US, for some `Intent` structures, you will always get an HTC-supplied mediator activity class -- [see this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/23/linkify-problem-patent-behavior.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and all the wisdom you are sharing through your books. I will try this.

Comment: Also how do I check if the returned ResolveInfo is for the chooser activity?

Comment: @febinkk: Look at the `activityInfo` of the `ResolveInfo`. I forget what the name and package of the chooser activity is, but it should be recognizable if you experiment a bit.

Comment: Thanks again, I will find the name and package, I was jst afraid that hard-coding the name, and package was not a good idea. But now I guess that it is unavoidable.

Comment: @febinkk: Yeah, I have no idea how you would determine that it's the chooser except by hard-coding. Another option is for you to look into `getPreferredActivities()` and figure out if what you want is in there.